# Convert vector to a word with Fasttext

Tags: python, word2vec, fasttext

I made a model with a dataset with Fasttext and I can convert every word to a vector.
But now I want to convert a vector to its unique word.

For example, I have this vector that is for (**"the"**) word and I want to convert it to its word with my Fasttext model.

```py
[-0.0193,  0.1951, -0.1819, -0.3403,  0.3106,  0.2078, -0.0274,
  0.0346, -0.0239,  0.1478, -0.0802, -0.0720,  0.2250,  0.0943,
 -0.0288, -0.0493,  0.1270, -0.0680, -0.1122,  0.0083, -0.0060,
  0.1109, -0.0454, -0.2186,  0.0731,  0.0368,  0.1594,  0.0640,
                        ....
 -0.1320,  0.2031,  0.1679, -0.0396, -0.2523, -0.0785, -0.0268,
  0.0182, -0.0330, -0.2324, -0.1024, -0.1578,  0.2445, -0.0421,
 -0.0757,  0.0089, -0.2211,  0.0022, -0.2253, -0.0776]
```

It's a `(,300)` dim vector. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An origin vector oesn't necessarily have a unique word. Rather, FastText models can often report a ranked list of the words *nearest* your target vector. (Of course, if your vector does in fact match the word's vector exactly, it will be the 1st item in this ranked list.)

I can't find a supported method in Facebook's `fasttext` Python wrapper for this - if it's there, it's not prominent in their docs.

But in the alternative Python 'gensim' library – which can load FastText models from elsewhere – the method to use is `.most_similar()`:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.FastTextKeyedVectors.most_similar

Specifically, it can take *either* words or vectors as the items in its `positve` & `negative` parameters. To get the nearest-neighbors of a single vector `vec`, you could use:

```
    ranked_neighbors = ft_model.most_similar(positive=[vec])
```

The list you get back includes both words and their similarity-scores, so to just get the single best match (no matter how far it is from your target), you could use:

```
    top_hit = ranked_neighbors[0][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks, i could do it with this code :

```
from gensim.models.fasttext import load_facebook_model

vector = [....]
result = model_g.wv.most_similar(positive=[vector], topn=1)
word = result[0][0] 

print(word)
```

Comment: You can't answer like this. Maybe edit your question.